# Changing ksh dir when exiting bash mode

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My default shell is ksh but I like to use bash to browse directories so when I found what I wanted I exit from bash and I wanted to have my ksh dir set to the same dir as bash was when I exited it.

for example:

```
1 - Log in

2 - $ ps -p && | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
    ksh
    $ pwd
    /home/myuser

3 - $ bash
    $ ps -p && | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
    bash 
    $ pwd 
    /home/myuser
    $ cd dir1
    $ cd dir2
    $ pwd 
    /home/myuser/dir1/dir2
    $ exit

4   $ ps -p && | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'
    ksh
    $ pwd
    /home/myuser
```

So at the end of step 3 when I exited bash shell I would like to have my ksh to have the same dir as bash had.

So in the example above when I ran step 4 I would like to to have my pwd set to /home/myuser/dir1/dir2 automaticaly. Does anyone know how to do that trick ?

I know that if I type ksh instead of exit I will have the same dir but I don't want to start a new session everytime I need to "browse" dirs.

Environment: AIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up resolving like this:

I added  to my ~/.bash_logout the following line:

```
pwd >~/.place
```

Then I created this alias in my .kshrc

```
alias bashcd = 'bash -l;cd `cat ~/.place`'
```

it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

When `bash` exits, it executes the file `~/.bash_logout` if it exists. So first write a `.bash_logout` that records the current directory:

```
pwd >~/.place
```

Then write a `ksh` function that calls `bash`, then does a `cd` to the directory recorded in the file:

```
bashcd()
{
     bash --login
     cd $(cat ~/.place)
}
```

The `--login` is needed because `bash` will not run `.bash_logout` if it isn't a "login shell". Define the function in your `~/.kshrc` file, then use `bashcd` instead of `bash`.

Comment: It's not what exactly what I wanted but it end up giving me a good tip: ./bash_logout is called when you exit. FYI it only got called after I called bash with argument -l. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It can't be done.  A sub-shell, such as your invocation of bash, is completely unable to influence its parent.

Comment: Even if they "talk" each other using a tempfile that would contain the dirname ?